# Unity game too dark in android device?

Tags: unity-game-engine

My Unity Game in android device is too dark. I added Sprites to my game and that sprites very dark. I tried to added lights but lights also not working.I am getting following warning on every light object `Lighting has been disabled in at least...` And also tried to enable lighting in the scene view. **On UNITY Editor it is not dark . But it is too dark on ANDROID **

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it belongs to https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. We are ready to help you if you provide enough information on the matter of the problem. Please read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/help/asking) first to be able to ask a proper question.

Comment: Give some extra details. At least the complete warning

Comment: @Ignacio in my every project the game is too dark.Where can I add brightness to the game

Comment: You mean every scene is dark? What type of light are you adding in the scenes? Each type has its of features and parameters

Comment: Yes every scene..Every light... directional ,spotlight. .

Comment: Does it happen when you build it too? Just build it and check

Comment: @Programmer  Yes. Why is lighting is not working. I tried to increase intensity,range. nothing not working

Comment: Sorry, I don't know why. You may want to upload your scene somewhere and provide the link here. We I get time, I will take a look at it.

Comment: @Programmer I added more details in my question.

Comment: @EgyuHook it's not any better, really. Try capturing a picture of what is happening, also show us your scene in the editor with sprite selected and then some light source selected

Comment: @Fiiffe I have problem with android. Maybe I have to change some settings on Player Settings.

Comment: Is your mobile device brightness settings set to dark?

Comment: Commend on the [other](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45412322/how-to-wait-until-first-function-will-done) question you asked not this one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You provided close to no information about the problem but...

Try setting your lights to `Render Mode: Important` in Inspector, also check your Quality Settings for `pixel light count` and make the default value higher.

If you want more accurate answers that will help you resolve your problems faster - try adding some pictures of the problem and the whole error log.

Answer (score 0):

I fix this problem by changing color space from linear to gamma

You can change this property in player settings -> other settings:
[image: You can change this property in player settings -> other settings]