# How to wait until first function will done?

Tags: unity-game-engine

I have two functions.The first function takes 2 seconds.  Second function must wait until the second will finish.  This is my following code.

```
     void Update(){

      StartCoroutine("something");

        }

     IEnumerator something()
        {
           First();
           yield return null;
             Second();

        }
        void First(){
                      for(long i=0;i<2131232123123123;i++){
                          print(i);
}
        }
        void Second(){print("Done");}
```

Comment: @Programmer where I have to add `yield return new WaitForSeconds(2);`After `First` or before `First`

Comment: *"Second function must wait until the second will finish"* This does not even make sense. Please edit your question and explain this. Also add why the function will wait for 2 seconds and this will help you get a proper solution. Note that you use coroutine functions to wait not a void function.

Comment: I use your dublicate question for edit. So is that would wait 2 seconds?

Comment: I don't need  wait exactly 2 seconds. But The first function  takes some more time. So how to wait until `first` will finish? After then the second must start. Is that possible?

Comment: Yes, it it. It is called chaining coroutines. I added another duplicate link to this question. Check the second link I just added. It has an example of how to make functions call each other after another.